# Is there a website for rating and reviewing journals openly?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, editors

I always found remarkable that whilst the job of all my colleagues boils down to publishing papers, everyone seems so reserved and hesitant when it comes to discussing journals openly.

For instance, rather recently a website was created with exactly that objective, named Journalysis.org. Apparently it seems to have been shut down, as the link doesn't work from my side.

http://www.nature.com/news/rate-that-journal-1.17225

Some specific academic spheres have forums about this, e.g. https://journalreviews.princeton.edu/ranking-peer-reviewed-journals/

Please, can you give me examples of some broader websites or discussion Forums to openly discuss science journals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know just one site where you can review the manuscript submission process. It is called [SciRev.org](https://scirev.org):

> The idea for this website was born from our own experience with the scientific review process. This experience is similar to that of many colleagues: endlessly waiting for an uncertain outcome. Through SciRev.sc we aimed to improve this situation by offering researchers the opportunity to share their experiences and select an efficient journal to submit their work.

I don't know if this website is well-known by the scientific community, but I consulted it because I had some problems with a particular journal and I found comments from researchers that had the same issues as me. I think that it is pretty useful.

Comment: I like the concept of SciRev, but it doesn't seem to have collected much data. Perhaps because submitting a review requires a lot of effort.

Comment: I am enjoying this SciRev. It seems quite the kind of website I was searching for! I am amazed I'd never heard of it before, and it is a pity there are still few evaluations. I think we ought to promote this website immediately to colleagues. I am already adding reviews to all journals I've interacted with! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user2768 Indeed it is bureaucratic (mainly for creating an account) but on the other hand the system seems fair enough and not easily trolled. Also once you do all steps you see there are some nice services included, such as paid for reviewing and setting up personal notes and alerts about journals.